# Как сделать треугольную стрелку под табом?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать на css такую стрелку под активным табом?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Можно для этого использовать псевдоэлементы с `border`:

```js
// для демонстрации переключения табов
$('.block').on('click', function() {
  $('.block').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.block {
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: #000 solid 1px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block:before,
.block:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  border-width: 0px 10px 0 10px;
}

.block:before {
  border-top-color: #000;
}

.block:after {
  border-top-color: #fff;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.block.active:before,
.block.active:after {
  border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  TAB1
</div>
<div class="block active">
  TAB2
</div>
<div class="block">
  TAB3
</div>
<div class="block">
  TAB4
</div>
```

Comment: благодарю за решение. Кстати хотелось-бы уточнить, в вашем примере пресдоэлемент существует только при наличии класса .active. Может правильней нужно инициализировать псевдоэлементы для всех табов, но скрыть, а потом при добавлении класса active, показывать псевдоэлемент?

Comment: @word Можно его и к .block добавить, а при .active только отображать - тут на ваше усмотрение

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с использованием псевдоэлементов (`:before` и `:after`) + `transform: rotate`

```js
(function() {

  $('.block').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });

})();
```

```css
.block {
  background: #fff;
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.block.active{
  color: #f00;
  cursor: text;
}
.block.active::before,
.block.active::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -6px;
  background: #999;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.block.active::after {
  background: #fff;
  bottom: -4px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block active">
  TAB1
</div>
<div class="block">
  TAB2
</div>
<div class="block">
  TAB3
</div>
<div class="block">
  TAB4
</div>
```